# Querying data from multiple odbc connections simultaneously?

Tags: sql, jdbc, crystal-reports, odbc, intersystems

I am creating a report with Crystal 2011. With all the reports I create with Crystal, I code the SQL first, then drop it into Crystal and use its formatting tools.

We have Intersystem's Cache database. In the report I am currently creating, I need to pull data from our production, testing, and sandbox environments into this single report. Each environment has a unique jdbc url.

In the report I will be comparing data between the environments looking for discrepancies.

Does anyone have any ideas how to pull data via multiple jdbc/odbc connections into a single report?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sub Reports can can point to different database connection.

Comment: I have three subreports and each one is pointing to a different database connection. The Main Report is not pointing to any database connection. I would like to somehow pass data from each subreport to the main report via a variable, or array and perform calculations on the data. Is that possible? The more I have been trying to figure it out, the more I'm leaning toward it is absolutely impossible, unless someone knows something i don't. Thanks! Steve

Comment: Look for shared variable, these allow to pass value from sub report to main report.